# Primefaces backbean bean update taken time

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I try to update panel using backbean update it becuase

**one.xhtml**

```
.....
<h:form>
<p:panel id="contentPanel">
.....
<ui:include src="#{main.pagePath}/>
</p:panel

</h:form>
```

**two.xhtml**

```
.......
<h:form>
....
<p:commandButton id="save" action="#{user.saveAction} update=currentpanel,:#{p:component('contentPanel')}/>
</h:form>
```

In this update saveButton validation failed need update current panel but it also update contentPanel  so I try backbean to update

**user.java**

```
public String saveAction()
{
if(validateFiled)
{
....
.....
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance.update('contentPanel');
}
return null;
}
```

**But it taken more time to update panel**

Comment: update=currentpanel,:#{p:component('contentPanel')}/ Explain is this corect c/p

Answer (score 0):

To update a component on front side you need to select the component with some CSS or jQuery selector. eg. `update="@form"` or `update="@(.className)"` or full component id

```
update=":formID:namingContainerIDifExsists:componentID"
```

In back bean you need to put a full id component like yo see it in console, or debug:

RequestContext.getCurrentInstance.update('formID:contentPanel');

If you have multiple forms give them an unique id